I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have set the pam password complexity in pam module file . How to ignore pam password complexity for a user
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have set the pam password complexity in pam module file (/etc/pam.d/common-passwd). How to ignore pam password complexity for a user. Below is the restriction I am using
password requisite pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=20 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1

Welcome to ASK. It is my understanding that the configuration file for PAM is /etc/pam.conf and it includes the general behavior of the PAM suites. The directory /etc/pam.d contains a dedicated configuration file for each application that uses PAM. See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/password-complexity for more details

As an example, if you want to ignore the pam_pwquality.so check for the user ubuntu then a simple solution would be to use this common-passwd configuration.
password        [success=ignore default=1]      pam_succeed_if.so user = ubuntu
password        [success=3 default=die]         pam_unix.so obscure yescrypt
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass yescrypt
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so

It is a bit more confusing than I'd like because the pam_unix.so module expects pam_pwquality.so to provide the password when it is used.
